# Material ui DatePicker enable only year

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

Is there any way to show **only** *years* in **Material UI DatePicker** with **react**?
I want to allow the user to be able to select only the `year` and **not** *months* **or** *days*.
Note: The option `openToYearSelection` does not achieve this neither does `autoOk` help.

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue and the way i have sorted it out is by using **[material-ui-pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/)** library
Here is an example:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker, InlineDatePicker } from "material-ui-pickers";

function YearMonthPicker(props) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="picker">
        <DatePicker
          views={["year"]}
          label="Year only"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
          animateYearScrolling
        />
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default YearMonthPicker;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use views prop for mui DatePicker.

```
<DatePicker views={['year']} />
```

Also you can disable some years using **shouldDisableYear** prop.

https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/